# Method miscalculates number of vowels

Tags: java, variable-assignment

My assignment asks me to read a file and print the number of vowels in each line. And for some odd reason, it prints the right amount of vowels in some lines, but not in others. Why is it doing this?!

Here's my method to calculate the vowels:

```
public static int calculateVowels(String line) 
{
    char[] vowels = new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u'};

    // count the number of vowels in a line
    int vowelCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        char a = line.charAt(i);
        for (char vowel : vowels) {
            if (a == vowel){
                vowelCount++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowelCount;
}
```

And here it is when I call it in main:

```
while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) 
{
    lineCount++;
    // count the number of words in a line
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    if (words != null)
    wordCount += words.length;

    int vowelCount = calculateVowels(line);
    System.out.println("Line " + lineCount + " has " + vowelCount + " vowels.");
}
```

Any ideas?! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting only lowercase vowels. My guess is, the count is off at lines which contain sentences/capitalized words beginning with a vowel. You can use this test:

```
Character.toLowerCase(a) == vowel
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to count both without writing all the upper case vowels too?

Comment: Use this String method:  `.compareToIgnoreCase(String);`

Comment: 'str.compareToIgnoreCase(string)' VS 'Character.toLowerCase(string)' , any much difference ?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh You have the signature wrong: it's `Character.toLowerCase(char)`, which is the main point: if you operate on chars, then use that; if you have strings, then use `String#equalsIgnoreCase`.